# How to restrict function calls to certain 'type' of users in Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I recently shifted from using Composer to writing ChainCode in Go. In Composer, using ACL, I could restrict certain transactions to specific `participant` types.

I'm attempting to build a multi-org network where user 'types' are defined as structs in Go -- `Client` `Agent` and `Manager`

I want the `Client` to have access to certain transactions, `Agent` to have access to a different set of transactions, and `Manager` to have access to all of `Agent`'s and some more transactions.

How do I implement this using Fabric Go chaincode? Appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this section in the Fabric Docs https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#chaincode-access-control and this chaincode sample https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode/abac/go - based on Attributes in the Client Certificate.

Comment: Oh this is great thanks a lot @RThatcher

Answer (score 1):

OK so lets assume Alice is an Agent. There is a function `onlyAgent()` that you want to ensure can be called only by Alice. It will be something like this

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) createParticipant (stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    username := args[0]; // This would be Alice
    type := args[1]; // This should be Agent
    user := &marble{type , username }
    userAsJsonBues, err := json.Marshal(user )
    err = stub.PutState(marbleName, userAsJsonBues);
    return shim.Success(nil);
}

func (t *SimpleChaincode) onlyAgent(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    username := args[0]; // Expects to be Alice
    aliceAsBytes, err := stub.GetState(username)
    alice:= User{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(aliceAsBytes, &alice)
    // alice.user should return Agent. Perform whatever checks you want
}
```

This should give you a rough idea on how to proceed, couple of things to remember

1. This example requires the name Alice to be passed as parameter in `onlyAgent`. I did it for demonstrative purposes, technically you would want to extract Alice's certificate and then query Alice directly from that (I can do this in `nodejs` chaincode but can't seem to find the exact API call in `go`)

Comment: Thanks. The code is not necessarily useful for me but from your comment I was able to look into further and found out ABAC, will be digging deeper into it.

Comment: Ya that is a better example, thing is I remember seeing an issue open for this, but was not sure if the feature was rolled out/ merged.Using `attributes` in the client certificate is probably a better way, but I have been using the way I mentioned for now.